# How can I split Flask search engine results into different pages?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, heroku

I've created a search engine using Flask that returns search results from a Wikipedia corpus generated from articles relating to the topic of health. Some queries return hundreds of results, so I would like to add a feature that splits the results up into multiple pages. Below is the `index.html` code that generates the webpage:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Search Page{% endblock %}
{% block contents %}

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="search-result-box card-box">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
              <div class="pt-3 pb-4">
                <div class="search-form">
                  <form action="#" method="POST">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="msg" class="form-control input-lg">                    
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn  btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
                </div>

                <div class="mt-4 text-center"><h4>Search Results For {{user_query}}</h4></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end row -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-bordered">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-link active">All results <span class="badge badge-success ml-1">{{search_results_list|length}}</span></a></li>
          </ul>
             <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="search-item">
                                {% if search_results_list|length > 0 %}

                                {% for r in search_results_list %}

                                <div class="font-13 text-success mb-3"><a href='{{r[0]}}' target="_blank">{{r[0]}}</a></div>
                                <div class="font-13 text-success mb-3"><p target="_blank">{{r[1]}}</p></div>

                                {% endfor %}
                                {% else %}
                                <p class="mt-4 text-center">No search result</P>
                                {% endif %}
                              </div>
                                <ul class="pagination justify-content-end pagination-split mt-0">
                                  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a></li>
                                  <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                                  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></li>
                              </ul>
                              <div class="clearfix"></div>
                           </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end All results tab -->

              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="main-footer" class="pt-2 py-4 bg-dark text-white text-center">
    Copyright &copy;
    <span class="year"></span> Team Dream
  </footer>
  <!-- container -->


{% endblock %}
```

I don't have a lot of experience creating web pages with HTML so I'm not totally sure how to add this feature. Also here is the Python code that generates the app:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from search_engine import query_prep, OkapiBM25
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def results():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def process_res():
    with open("inv_index.pickle", "rb") as file:
        inv_ind = pickle.load(file)
    user_search_query = request.form['msg']
    queries = {'q': query_prep(user_search_query)}
    ranking = OkapiBM25(inv_ind, queries)['q']
    seen = set()

    newRes= []
    myDict = pickle.load(open('text_summaries.pickle','rb'))
    
    for r in ranking:
        newRes.append((r[1], myDict[r[1]]))

    return render_template('index.html', search_results_list = newRes,
                                          user_query=user_search_query)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The code opens a pickle file with the inverted index of the corpus and then runs the query against the index, ranks the results, and returns them. There are also text summaries of each Wikipedia article that appear below each search result. Here is the deployed version of the web page if you want to play around with it and see what I'm trying to do: https://searchenginecapstone.herokuapp.com/

If you search "health," you'll see that there are 442 results on one page. I want to adapt the code (and I think this would be done solely in the HTML portion--but not totally sure) to split the results into chunks of 10-20. There already is a button at the bottom right of the page for Pages, but it currently doesn't do anything. I appreciate any help or ideas you can offer. Let me know if there is anything else you need to see from the coding side to answer this question.

I see that Flask has native support for pagination with the `paginate()` method, so if I modify what's returned in `render_template()` with the following:

```
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_parameter

    def process_res():
    with open("inv_index.pickle", "rb") as file:
        inv_ind = pickle.load(file)
    user_search_query = request.form['msg']
    queries = {'q': query_prep(user_search_query)}
    ranking = OkapiBM25(inv_ind, queries)['q']
    seen = set()

    newRes= []
    myDict = pickle.load(open('text_summaries.pickle','rb'))
    
    for r in ranking:
        newRes.append((r[1], myDict[r[1]]))

    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=len(newRes), search=user_search_query, record_name='Search Results')
    return render_template('index.html', search_results_list = newRes,
                                          user_query=user_search_query,
                                          Pagination = pagination)
```

The page seems to work (without the pagination appearing), so I think I have to update the index file to reflect the pagination changes but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension, you can use the paginate() method to split the search engine results into different pages.

Comment: I tested that out and wasn't sure where to apply the `.paginate()` method. I tried it here: `return render_template('index.html', search_results_list = newRes.paginate(page=1, per_page=20, error_out=False).items, user_query=user_search_query)`
but that errored out.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I could integrate that logic into my approach?